# Detection of the outer circle using cv::HoughCircles

Tags: opencv

A complete newbie for opencv here. I am trying to detect the outer circle in this image using the HoughCircle detection. I have read that detection of concentric circles is an issue with HoughCircle algorithm. Nevertheless, I havent been able to detect just the outer circle. I have been using the Houghcircle demo provided in 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html
(The 6th and 7th argument values for the houghcircles method are 80 and 36 respectively, 8th and 9th are both 0. i.e.
HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray.rows / 8, 80, 36, 0, 0);)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: It is always better to convert your image to a binary image, you may use `cv2.threshold()` to get a binary image which contains the outer circle (play with the threshold values, to get desired output.) Then running `HoughCircles()` on it would get you better results.

Comment: @ZdaR, thanks that helped. But now I have a lot of false circles being detected. I just need to play around with the HoughCircles() parameters to neglect the false positives :)

Comment: No, now you can use `cv2.findContours()` on the binary image, then filter the contours using `cv2.contourArea()`, you can set an accepted range and ignore other small contours. :)